# Ubuntu 18.04 kernel panic on shutdown

Tags: kernel, 18.04, alienware

I am having trouble when shutting down Dell Alienware Aurora R7 after installing ubuntu 18.04. The nvidia drivers were successfully installed.

[image]

Comment: I faced the same issue myself and found a solution. See my answer here for the instructions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446913/52937

Comment: @yttrium Could you copy-paste your answer from U&L to AU as the question might be closed because it's a bug... (Already upvoted over there, will do same here if you ping me)  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby copy-pasted.

Answer (score 6):

### Copy-pasting answer from U&L as per people request

After reading kernel sources, I found a function we need to blacklist!

Thanks to [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) for the hint about `initcall_blacklist`.

Add `initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver` to the kernel command line. This works for me on kernel 4.15.0.

For anyone else who'll find this answer. You can do it by editing `/etc/default/grub`:

1. Run in the terminal: `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. Append blacklist string to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="… initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver"`.
3. Save the file, close the editor.
4. Run in the terminal: `sudo update-grub`.
5. Reboot and test!

Comment: And upvoted as promised! **:-)**

Comment: thank you so much @yttrium. it worked perfectly

Comment: I am using a Dell Aurora R7 w/ a Nvidia 1070Ti. I am running Kubuntu 18.04.2 on the 4.18.0 kernel and this worked for me.

Comment: Also on a Dell Aurora R7 and this resolved the issue! Thanks a ton stephen-kitt!